# Node.js does not serve css files

Tags: css, node.js

I am using the socket.io framework to get data from my custom made IoT device. The device uses TCP/IP protocol and my website uses HTTP protocol. So, there is no problem with communication but I can't see any css style in the web page.

I have so many css files and css file destination.

[This is expected screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izspz.png)

[My file index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGZy.png)

Here is my server.js code:

```
// socket io
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    exp = express();

exp.use('*/css',express.static('css'));

app.listen(80, function() {
  console.log('Socket IO Server is listening on port 80');
});

function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  })
};


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connection...');
  socket.on('emit_from_client', function(data) {
    console.log('socket.io server received : '+data);
    io.emit('emit_from_client', data);
  });
});

// TCP server
var net = require('net');
var writable = require('fs').createWriteStream('test.txt');


net.createServer(function (socket) {
  console.log('socket connected');
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    var line = data.toString();
    console.log('got "data"', line);
    socket.pipe(writable);
    io.emit('emit_from_client', line); // socket.io
    //socket.emit("OK\r\n"); // socket.io
    socket.write("OK1\r\n");
  });
  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
  });
  socket.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close');
  });
  socket.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error ', e);
  });
  socket.write('Hello from tcp server\r\n');
}).listen(3080, function() {
  console.log('TCP Server is listening on port 3080');
});
```

This is my index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Sensemeister HVAC</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socketz = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socketz.emit('emit_from_client', $('#sicaklikSet').val());
      $('#sicaklikSet').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socketz.on('emit_from_client', function(data){
//var data = "ID101;Main;24.0;3276.0;3276.0;0;0;1;30.0;3;76.0;85.0;25.0*";

  var tokens = data.toString().split(";");
  tokens[tokens.length-1] = tokens[tokens.length-1].split("*",1);
  for(var i=2; i< tokens.length; ++i)//first two param not necessary
  {
  var idStr = 'dataToken' + i.toString();
  document.getElementById(idStr).innerHTML = tokens[i];
  }

      //$('#messages').text(data);
    });
  });

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#onOffButton").text("Hello world!");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
    });
    $("#btn3").click(function(){
        $("#test3").val("Dolly Duck");
    });
});

</script>


</head>
</code>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `exp.use('/css/*',express.static('css'));
`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your assets are [statically available](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```
app.use(express.static('css'))
```

Since your assets are not accessible this way, the same is not reflecting in your output

As [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638668/node-js-does-not-serve-css-files/48638716#comment84273606_48638668) by [@ArpitSolanki](https://stackoverflow.com/u/5250746), try:

```
exp.use('/css/*',express.static('css'));
```

Also, as per your code:

```
exp.use('*/css',express.static('css'));
```

I have never seen such kind of path working.